# Element won't go to bottom on Chrome, too small 'top' on Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with one of the elements on my site.
On others browser works fine, but only in Chrome I get this:
[image]

And on Edge I got this:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Here is demo: [LINK](http://demo.vrs-factory.pl/gl/)

Comment: Please add a starting point in code (for example a JSFiddle or CodePen) to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please describe what exactly is wrong here

Comment: Your quest for the [holy grail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Grail_(web_design)) will not be easy.

Comment: So it should look like this, and it looks like the pictures.[link](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/9698817?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1460036109&Signature=kwHXqX9c81S5AwFw86P5jb2cDFY%3D)

Comment: @Roy I ordered all the code and left only what you need so should now be more clearly.

Comment: Chrome and Edge looks identical (if not, very similar) http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGTrz.png

Comment: @Sampson but look on it on full resolution

Answer (score 0):

The `div class="job-box-goto">` has been positioned.

```
   @media (min-width: 768px)
      .Job section.job-list .job-list-content .job-box .job-box-goto {
        position: relative;
        top: -79px; /* delete this */
    }
```

Try removing the positioning